# API стран, городов

Tags: api, rest, location

создаю сайт, столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть нормальное Api со списком стран, городов, улиц и тд?
Как это лучше использовать или лучше самому создать?
В гугле почти нет об этом информации.
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: что именно должно уметь api?

Comment: JSON список стран и городов

Comment: тоесть нужны список названий стран и список названий городов? или их всё-таки нужно среди них _как-то_  _что-то_ искать по _каким-то_ параметрам?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что именно вам нужно. Готового API такого я не встречал. Но получение информации из баз данных - не сильно сложнее. 
Бесплатные БД есть и для всего мира, и для отдельных стран. Всемирные не содержат улиц. 
Вот парочка, которых я нашёл:

- http://www.worldcitiesdatabase.com/world-cities.aspx
- http://www.geodatasource.com/world-cities-database/free
- https://www.maxmind.com/ru/free-world-cities-database

Если нужно для какой-то конкретной страны - ищите в гугле, их огромное множество и с улицами.

Answer (score 0):

Со своей стороны я бы предложил сделать выборку под свои нужды и требования. В качестве источника информации, я бы порекомендовал дампы Википедии и ОпенСтритМапс, я их много раз парсил и получал необходимые выборки.

https://dumps.wikimedia.org/ruwiki/20200601/
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data

Более простой вариант - спарсить какой-нибудь сайт с прогнозами погоды или доставками